# Image "shaking" on CSS div transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a DIV with this CSS on hover:

```
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

And inside this div, I have an image with this CSS:

```
.card .avatar {
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that the image seems to be "shaking" a bit when the transition occurs.

Here´s the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zudvv4cv/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the transform property instead of margin

```
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  transform:translate(-5px, -5px);
}
```

Make sure you have used all proper prefixes

```
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #c4c4c4;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-5px, -5px);
          transform:translate(-5px, -5px);
}
```

Sample https://jsfiddle.net/zudvv4cv/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `transform: translate(x,y)` to do the transition, its ignoring the position of sourrounding elements.

`transform: translate(-5px, -5px);`